# MySQL query: trying to combine the information of two tables

Tags: mysql

I am stuck trying to build a query for my database by combining the information in two different tables:

The first one is called `item_distribution` and has two columns: one for a `folder_ID` and another for an `item_ID`.

And the second one is called `item_tags` and has two columns as well: one for a `tag_ID` and another for an `item ID`.

Let's imagine a situation:

In the first table I have the following information (which items are in which folders):

```
folder_ID      item_ID
00001          00001
00001          00002
00001          00003
00002          00004
00001          00005
00001          00006
```

And in the second table, the following rows (which items have which tags):

```
tag_ID         item_ID
00001          00001
00002          00001
00003          00001
00001          00002
00003          00002
00001          00003
00002          00003
00001          00004
00001          00005
00002          00005
```

How could I get the distinct `item_ID` of all the items which are in folder 00001 and have both the tags 00001 AND 00002? Is it possible with only one query expression?

Thanks a lot!

Oriol

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
select distinct f.item_ID
from folders f
join tags t1 on f.itemID = t1.item_ID and t1.tag_ID = '00001'
join tags t2 on f.itemID = t2.item_ID and t2.tag_ID = '00002'
where f.folder_ID = '00001'
```

Comment: @user597009 You're welcome.  Please consider accepting (and/or up-voting) the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  You should do this for all the questions you've asked which got a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to list them all use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM item_distribution ID
LEFT JOIN item_tags IT ON ID.item_ID = IT.item_id;
```

That will return both tables joined together.

You can add a where clause after the join to narrow your results (per folder or per item for example).

```
WHERE ID.folder_ID = '00001';
```